# Error handling unvalid data with: invalid + express node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying invalid with express,

I saw this great example on their page:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/isvalid#example-1

I've done something similar in my code:

```
module.exports = app.post(
'/', 
validate.body({ 
    'email': { type: String, required: true },
    'password' : { type: String, required: true}
}),
function (req, res) {
    res.send("We got the email: " + email + "And password: " + password);
}
```

my problem is, where do I handle the errors? currently I'm getting:

```
Error: Data is required.
    at validateAny ...
```

which is logical, cause the JSON I'm sending lacks password, which is a required field.

regarding their remark:

> Remark: If validation fails isvalid will unset the validated content 
>      (eg. req.body will become null if body validation fails). This is to 
>      ensure that routes does not get called with invalid data, in case a 
>      validation error isn't correctly handled.

I don't get it has null, just the exception.

when I send a valid json body, it works great.

So..

Where can I insert same error handling?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
I've needed to add:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err)
  res.status(400).send('Validation failed')
})
```

And my error was there.

Thanks, and hope it will help someone.